# Azure MySql In App With App Service .NET 6 - EF6 - Unable to Connect

Tags: c#, mysql, azure

From what I can tell the best way to get the Azure MySql In App Database connection string is to read the MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb environment variable. I am just experimenting right now.

I am using .NET 6, Entity Framework 6, and MYSQL. I have a Mysql 5.7 db setup on my local computer, which I can tell is the same version that Azure MySql In App Database uses.

I have created a DbContext class and an Items DbSet from an Item Db model. I created the database and table using PhpMyAdmin through Azure, so I know that at least PHPMyAdmin is working. I also created the database and Item table in my local MySql database using the MySQL workbench. Everything works on my local computer / debugging with IIS express. For convenience sake I am just using a right-click publish to publish this app to Azure. The deploy does go well. And the site works until I try to interact with the database. I created a link to the /Items/Index page in my menu for convenience. But it tells me that it cannot connect to the SQL server. I even have added the connnection string to a ViewBag property on a page to be sure that it is reading the MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb environment variable correctly. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The specific errors that I receive are:
MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, int startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in ServerSession.cs
MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, string logMessage, int startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in ConnectionPool.cs
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, int startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in ConnectionPool.cs
MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, int startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in ConnectionPool.cs
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, int startTickCount, Nullable ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in MySqlConnection.cs
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in MySqlConnection.cs
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(bool errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(bool errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool errorsExpected)
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy+<>c__DisplayClass33_0<TState, TResult>+<b__0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync<TState, TResult>(Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult>> verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

and

RetryLimitExceededException: The maximum number of retries (3) was exceeded while executing database operations with 'MySqlRetryingExecutionStrategy'. See the inner exception for the most recent failure.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync<TState, TResult>(Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult>> verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
WebApplication22.Controllers.ItemsController.Index() in ItemsController.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask actionResultValueTask)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Here is the relevant portion of my Program.cs (using new .net 6 style of "main" method)

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<MyDbContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseMySql(
        System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb"),
        new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 9)),
        mySqlOptions =>
        {
            mySqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), null);            
        });
});
```

MyDbContext class:

```
    public class MyDbContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<DbModels.Item> Items { get; set; }

        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> dbConfiguration) : base(dbConfiguration)
        {
        }        
    }
```

Package references:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Items Controller using Dependency Injection...

```
    public class ItemsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public ItemsController(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Items
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Items.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Items/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var item = await _context.Items
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: Items/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Items/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name")] Item item)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(item);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: Items/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var item = await _context.Items.FindAsync(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // POST: Items/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name")] Item item)
        {
            if (id != item.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(item);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ItemExists(item.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: Items/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var item = await _context.Items
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(item);
        }

        // POST: Items/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var item = await _context.Items.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Items.Remove(item);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool ItemExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Items.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "But it tells me that it cannot connect to the SQL server." What is the exact error message and full call stack? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: Thank you. I added some of those additional details to the post.